# Unable to access userDefaults with standard

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have trouble with UserDefaults.

I already tried `userDefaults.standard` but it's not working. The userDefeaults with standard shows an error:

> "which is "Static member 'standard' cannot be used on instance of type 'UserDefaults'"

```
if user != nil {
    if userDefaults.standard.object
}
```

> Static member 'standard' cannot be used on instance of type 'UserDefaults'

Why can not accept the standard with userDefaults?

Comment: Show how you declared and initialize your `userDefaults` variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is how you can work with `UserDefaults`.

Get a reference to user defaults:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
```

Set an object for key "age":

```
defaults.set(31, forKey: "age")
```

Unwrap the value of the stored key. If it is nil (key does not exist), it will not enter the block.

```
if let object = defaults.object(forKey: "age") {
}
```

Comment: If you set an `Int` in `UserDefaults` then you can read it using `let someInt = defaults.integer(forKey: "age")`.

Comment: You are correct. It can be achieved using an Integer specifically when we want to store and read Integers. The idea in my answer was to show how we can store and read without an explicit type, as Haseena asked.
Thanks for clarifying.